# Calculated member disappearing when collapse group in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas

I am using Excel 2010 and SQL Analysis Services 2008 R2. I created a calculated member that adds up totals. It is shown below and works fine.

CalcMember = [Product].[Product].defaultmember - Aggregate ([Product].[Product].&[Test])

I have set the parent hierarchy to [Product].[Product] and the Parent Member to [All]. When I view this in Excel it looks good. However, if I collapse a group that contains the calculated member it disappears. If I expand the group then the calculated member appears. For example:

```
Expand
 Year
  - 2010
     Product1    50
     CalcMember  75
  - 2011
     Product2    25
     CalcMember  60

Collapse
 Year
   + 2010
   - 2011
     Product2    25
```

Why does the CalcMember disappear from year 2011? How do I get it not to disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesnt play nicely with Calculated Members.  I would add a "real" member into the Product dimension e.g. with a Union.  Then instead of defining a Calculated Member, I would use a SCOPE assignment to perform the calculation.